Determine or indicate if Linux process is started by web user (apache) or cronjob?
On my server, python scripts can be started either through a cronjob, or through our website (via apache).  Sometimes I want to kill processes started by one, but not the other.  When I run htop, it looks like the user is "ubuntu" for both.  Is there a way to determine natively which process started the script?  Or if not natively, indicate how it was started?
Ideally I'd write another script in python that would find those processes (let's say those started by apache) and kill them while leaving the cronjobs alone.  Meaning I can leverage both linux and python tools for this purpose.
UPDATE: Thanks for all the comments, they've opened up some avenues for me to try (namely the Process ID group and using a different user for the cronjob).  Will post an answer when I get it nailed down.

Look at the parent PID, to see if the parent is the apache process.

I should add that my understanding of Linux is very limited, but I see the PPID (thank you for that @Barmar) and will see if that helps.

Do they need to be started by the same user? Could you make them different users, and use pgrep -u <user> <process name> to identify processes run by one or the other?

@NickODell I don't need to have them started by the same user, but my knowledge of linux / apache is so limited I don't even know how to change that.  Not sure if it would be easier to change the cronjob user or the apache user.

How did you set up the cronjob in the first place? Every user gets their own table of cron jobs.

@elPastor Probably easier to change cronjob user. You can edit another user's crontab using sudo crontab -u user -e. See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/352835/crontab-running-as-a-specific-user

I know nothing about your setup but if your web-accessible server is running under a human user id (esp with sudo privileges), you probably need to reorganize it

Thanks all - just posted an update.  Should be good at this point.

There's usually a unique user used for apache, named something like www-data or www-user.

@Barmar - yes, apache starts using www-data, but each command after that goes through as ubuntu.  Not sure why.
